# Issue with Excel Export in sap.ui.table

Tags: sapui5

I have a requirement to export sap.ui.table data into excel.
The data is coming from OData Service and it is binded to sap.ui.table through row binding aggregation.

Please find below respective coding.

XML - sap.ui.Table declaration

```
<table:Table id="idTblExistingProposal" selectionMode="None" visibleRowCount="22" class="sapUiSmallMargin">
        <table:toolbar>
                <Toolbar height='2rem'>
                    <ToolbarSpacer/>
                    <Button tooltip="Change Layout" icon="sap-icon://action-settings" press="openSetting"/>
                    <Button tooltip="Excel Download" icon="sap-icon://excel-attachment" press="exportToExcel"/>
                    </Toolbar>
        </table:toolbar>
</table:Table>
```

onInit Method - Initial sapu.ui.table Bindings are done.

```
var columnData = [{
                    columnName: "Proposal ID",
                    id: "ProposalVer",
                    visible: true,
                    sortProperty: "ProposalVer"
                }, {
                    columnName: "Sold To (Customer)",
                    id: "SoldToName",
                    visible: true,
                    sortProperty: "SoldToName"
                }, {
                    columnName: "End Customer",
                    id: "EnduserName",
                    visible: true,
                    sortProperty: "EnduserName"
                }];

var oTable = this.getView().byId("idTblExistingProposal");
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModel.setData({
    rows: [],
    columns: columnData
});
oTable.setModel(oModel);
oTable.bindColumns("/columns");
oTable.bindRows("/rows");
```

Excel Export code which is called on toolbar sap.ui.table button click.

```
exportToExcel: function (oEvt) {
            var oTable = this.getView().byId("idTblExistingProposal");
            var aColumns = oTable.getColumns();
            var aTemplate = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < aColumns.length; i++) {
                var oColumn = {
                    name: aColumns[i].getLabel().getText(),
                    template: {
                        content: {
                            path: "/columns" + "/" + i
                        }
                    }
                };
                aTemplate.push(oColumn);
            }
            var oExport = new sap.ui.core.util.Export({
                exportType: new sap.ui.core.util.ExportTypeCSV({
                    separatorChar: "\t",
                    mimeType: "application/vnd.ms-excel",
                    charset: "utf-8",
                    fileExtension: "xls"
                }),
                // Pass in the model created above
                models: oEvt.getSource().getParent().getParent().getModel(),
                // binding information for the rows aggregation
                rows: {
                    path: "/rows"
                },
                columns: aTemplate
            });
            // download exported file
            oExport.saveFile().catch(function (oError) {
                MessageBox.error("Error when downloading data.\n\n" + oError);
            }).then(function () {
                oExport.destroy();
            });
        }
```

PFB Excel Output.

[image: Excel Output]

Please guide.

Regards,
Sayed

Comment: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.Table/sample/sap.m.sample.TableExport/code/Table.controller.js

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution.

By replacing the field value path in below code, export worked!.

Old code:

```
var oColumn = {
                name: aColumns[i].getLabel().getText(),
                template: {
                    content: {
                        path: "/columns" + "/" + i
                    }
                }
            };
```

New code:

```
var oColumn = {
    name: aColumns[i].getLabel().getText(),
     template: {
      content:  {
        path: aColumns[i].getProperty("filterProperty")  
                }
              }
            };
```

Regards,
Sayed

Comment: You can accept your own answer to let others know that this issue is resolved now